# How to update grub in a encrypted partition

Tags: grub2, updates, encryption, ecryptfs

Yesterday I made an update in my Ubuntu 16.04. During the update, a grub screen appeared. A black screen with only this message :

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub >
```

I touch the TAB touch, it shows me a lot of commands, but I don't know which one would be useful.

I try to restart my computer, but I fall into this screen immediately, without loading Ubuntu.

I have make a Boot Repair report, you can see it in this link :
[boot-repair report](https://pastebin.com/usvf69A8)

I find some people which have the same problem. They say it's a grub problem, which can be corrupted during its update.

But I cannot simply update grub : the specific part of mine is that I use encryption of my disk. This is why Boot-repair cannot provide me a solution.

I ran a live-usb key with Ubuntu 14.04, I see my partition with my data, but I cannot access to it because of permissions (I don't have any right, so I cannot make backups).

I hope someone will help me to repair grub with this encryption.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have posted below before, but was delete, because question asked was similar problem with grub, but without encryption. This is how I solved my grub problem with LUKS encryption:

After updating (by ubuntu software) my laptop today (after not using it for one week) I have the same problem. Only a grub prompt. Also first tried Boot-Repair on Live USB, but didn't work. My laptop is luks encrypted, so searched for other solutions, I found:

grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd3, gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
grub> insmod luks
grub> cryptomount hd0,3
Enter password
Slot 0 opened
grub> insmod lvm
grub> ls
(crypto0), etc.
grub> configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

This gives normal luks password entry screen, which accepted, but after that it immediatelly gives the following warning:

Welcome to emergency mode! Etc. I have looked at the journal and found (in red):
fsck failed with error code 4 and
Failed to start File System on /dev/disk/by-uuid/etc-etc.

Next thing I did was, enter maintance mode and command:
fsck /dev/sda2
After that I was able to log in normally, update by terminal and reboot. Did get another failure and had to run fsck /dev/sda2 again. After that I was able to reboot normally.

So this solved the above problem (when you have an encrypted LUKS disk).